# EDI X12 Documents - Documentation

Tags: edi, x12

Where can I find documentation on the X12 documents along with samples. I am interested in 810 and 812, but would also like to bookmark information on the additional documents.

Is there a good book out there which covers these documents?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There's a fair bit around.  The first place to look is [X12.org](http://www.x12.org).

This looks like a pretty decent [online course](http://www.courses.vcu.edu/INFO465-gs/ansi_x_12.htm).

EDI documents aren't particularly hard to process, they're just strings.  The difficulty is that within the standard there are a lot of degrees of freedom, so you need to negotiate exactly which field codes etc you're going to support with each transaction partner.

Another magic word to look for is [EDIFACT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIFACT), which is the [international standar](http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/welcome.htm)d.

Comment: I saw this earlier. They require membership for a fee. Isn't there official documentation for free somewhere?

Comment: Nope.  The standards organizations all charge for the documents.  But then I didn't link just to the standards, either.  Googling will also help.

Comment: He specifically asked about x12 which is different than EDIFACT.  I'm collecting my own set of documents on x12 specifications.  It is difficult to find detailed information without paying for the actual specification.

Answer (score 1):

You have to purchase the official documentation (from DISA), however for common X12 transactions like the 810 there are lots of implementation guides around on the net that have the subset of the transactions which are most used.